# Retrieve an image(Long Blob) from database(SQL) and display it into JLabel

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc, io

```
public void displayPhoto() {
    con = null;
    rs = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    BufferedImage bufImg = null;
    String displaySQL = "select * from images where USERNAME =?";
    try {
        con = getDBConnection();
        preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(displaySQL);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, currentuser.getText().trim());
        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            InputStream in = rs.getBinaryStream("IMAGES");
            bufImg = ImageIO.read(in);
            displayPhoto.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bufImg));
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

This is my code and it says `NullPointersException.`

Here is the full error message

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:228)
at MyProfile.displayPhoto(MyProfile.java:398)
at MyProfile.<init>(MyProfile.java:197)
at Login.actionPerformed(Login.java:93)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I've been doing this for a month and I still can't retrieve the image from database, sorry but I don't have any idea about ImageIO and Stream stuff,

- displayPhoto = `JLabel`

and it was positioned using `setBounds` in a `Container`

- `IMAGES` = column name,
- `images` = table name,
- `currentuser` = label with text of the user

How to do it and why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

You should check that your IMAGES column has no null values for that user.  However, the mostly likely cause is ImageIO is unable to read your stored bytes. According to the [ImageIO.read() javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29):

*If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned.*

The most likely cause is the IMAGE type is not one that ImageIO can handle, or it's corrupt and ImageIO can't read it.   As of JDK 1.7, ImageIO by default only handles the following image types:

- JPG
- PNG
- BMP
- WBMP
- GIF

If your images are a different type, you'll need to go through extra steps to read them.